# Type Error with ArcPy Update Cursor

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7

```
filter = 'LinkID IS NOT NULL' 
cur1 = arcpy.UpdateCursor("ODDS_Links", filter) 

high_id = 0
for row1 in cur1:
 if high_id < row1.LinkID:
  high_id = row1.LinkID



filter2 = 'LinkID IS NULL' 
cur2 = arcpy.UpdateCursor("ODDS_Links", filter2)

i = high_id
for row2 in cur2:
 i+=1
 row2.LinkID = str(i) 
 cur2.updateRow(row2)
```

The error I am getting is below. I know this works without the counter but something is wrong with counter and it won't add by one. If I comment out the counter it displays the error. I know I should use da but really don't feel like changing things around when I am so close.

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Comment: What is the data type of LinkID?

Comment: Is your 2nd cursor supposed to be in the loop of the first? Also, yes, you should swap to `da`.

Comment: No it is 2 separate loops

Comment: LinkID is a string currently. I will test with an int thanks. I thought that may be an issue.

Comment: Yes it was the data type that was the issue switching to an int solved the issue. Thanks  @dklassen

Answer (score 1):

Yes it was the data type that was the issue.

On advice of @dklassen switching the value passed to LinkID to an int data type solved the issue.